# Magento 1.9: dynamic config.xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm creating a Magento 1.9 module, and have so far defined settings(which work), then I went onto adding default values for my settings fields. Now, I was wondering, is it at all possible to have a value in config that's going to be linked to some other value? As in, I want to add default setting for the field where value will be Site name or site description.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not about coding"? My question is basically how to code what I asked in there. I really don't understand your comment at all. Is it beacause I didn't provide any code? It wouldn't be of any help, that's why I didn't.

Comment: It sound like you are asking about config settings for Magento. There's nothing here about coding as far as I can see. Can you try to code up as much of your solution as you can and then, we you get stuck, come ack with your code and ask again?

Comment: Well, the thing is that just now, I have everything in place and working. The problem is that I'm asking if that's possible to code. Did you read my question?

Comment: Yes, nothing about coding there, except you say you're creating a module. That, in and of itself, isn't coding. You need to show your code and what's going wrong. We're not a code writing or code design service. We're here to help you fix your specific programming issues.

Comment: Well, I still think you misunderstood me. When I say config, I mean config.xml, which is a configuration file for every magento module. So, no, there's nothing about tweaking admin settings here, I'm simply asking is it possible to do something by coding. I don't know where to start, hence no code from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create system.xml and use the below example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <folder translate="label" module="modulename">            
            <groups>
               <site_details>
                    <label>Website discription</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <name translate="label">
                            <label>Site name</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </name>
                        <description>
                            <label>description</label>
                            <comment><![CDATA[description]]></comment>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </description>
                    </fields>   
               </site_details>  
            </groups>
        </floder>
      </sections>
</config>
```